# moving the text in column to previous row on the basis of one column

Tags: r

I want to change the dataframe , i want to move text in all columns from second column to last column on the basis of column Region. so if there is any text start with !UK_ in Region the move the text from second to last column to previous row and make the current one as blank.

its not working as expected

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(data.table)
    
    df <-  tibble(Region = c("AU","USA","CA","USA","!UK_1","AU","USA","CA","!UK_north"),
                  lock = c(1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA),
                  type= c("sale",NA,NA,"target","target",NA,"sale",NA,"target"),
                  House =c("Tagore house","Gandhi house",NA,"Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house","Tagore house",NA,"Flexible;Gandhi house","Gandhi house","Gandhi house"))
    
    
    
    df <- mutate(df, rn3 = row_number())
    df1 <- df  %>%  filter(startsWith(Region,"!UK")) %>%
      transmute(House, rn3 = rn3 - 0.1) %>%  bind_rows(df, .) %>%
      mutate(House = if_else(Region  %in%  substr(Region, 1, 3) == "!UK", House[NA], House)) %>%  arrange(rn3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the data by duplicating the rows where there is `"!UK"` substring in Region, grouped by `consecutive_id` of 'Region', `replace` the rows having '!UK' to blank except the last row, similarly, loop `across` the other columns and replace the values to blank

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   uncount(str_detect(Region, fixed("!UK"))+1) %>%
  group_by(grp = consecutive_id(Region)) %>%
  mutate(Region = if(any(str_detect(Region, fixed("!UK"))))
    replace(Region, -n(), "") else Region,
   across(c(type, House), ~ replace(.x, str_detect(Region, fixed("!UK")),
    ""))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 4
   Region       lock type     House                               
   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>                               
 1 "AU"            1 "sale"   "Tagore house"                      
 2 "USA"           1  <NA>    "Gandhi house"                      
 3 "CA"           NA  <NA>     <NA>                               
 4 "USA"           1 "target" "Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house"
 5 ""             NA "target" "Tagore house"                      
 6 "!UK_1"        NA ""       ""                                  
 7 "AU"            1  <NA>     <NA>                               
 8 "USA"          NA "sale"   "Flexible;Gandhi house"             
 9 "CA"            1  <NA>    "Gandhi house"                      
10 ""             NA "target" "Gandhi house"                      
11 "!UK_north"    NA ""       ""
```